# Why does variable say undefined?

Tags: php, variables, undefined

This says $total and $sub is undefined for $total += $sub. $sub was declared in the while loop and both $sub are within the function so it should be a local variable.  Why can't I use it?

```
public function cart() {
    foreach($_SESSION as $name=>$value){
        if (substr($name, 0, 5) == 'cart_') {
            if((int)$value > 0){
                $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name)-5));

                $st = $this->db->prepare("select id, name, price from deals where id=?");
                $st->bindParam(1, $id);
                $st->execute();

                while($cart_item = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
                    $sub = $cart_item->price*$value;
                    echo $cart_item->name.' x '.$value.' @ '.$cart_item->price.' = '.$sub.' <a href="cart.php?add='.$id.'">[+]</a> <a href="cart.php?remove='.$id.'">[-]</a> <a href="cart.php?delete='.$id.'">[Delete]</a><br/>';
                }
            }
        }
        $total += $sub;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$total` variable should be initialized above your `foreach`. The `$sub` variable should be initialized inside the `foreach`, at the top.

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
    $sub = 0;
    ...
```

Also, you can move the `$total += $sub;` higher up, to be positioned just below the inner `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be a problem if

```
            $st = $this->db->prepare("select id, name, price from deals where id=?");
            $st->bindParam(1, $id);
            $st->execute();
```

Returns 0 results.

Define `$sub` before `foreach` and to be safe, `$total` as well:

```
$sub = $total = 0;
foreach(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

The undefined variable is $total, not $sub. Add $total=0; to the top of your function.

Comment: $sub could be undefined when `$st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)` returns no item

Answer (score 0):

You never initialized $total, hence the error.